# aptana studio 3 html Preview Button is DarkGrey , how to activate PreviewButton

Tags: aptana3

Newbie just installed 'aptana studio 3.3.2':
and I would like to open a Preview of the HtmlPage I am working on .
But  html Preview Button is DarkGrey , how to activate ? 
I remember at installTime , I unchecked PHP option . 
Could that have something to do with it ?

When I look at  Preferences/Aptana/Web Servers , 
it shows IP Address: 127.0.0.1    Port(s): 8020-8079 
Looks to me like server is configured ?
...Thanks...vm